# Function does not trigger when called from Scene/Stack component

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am trying to load icons into my tab bar. What I've discovered:

I have a function that needs to be run to determine what icon should be loaded, so in my `icon` attribute i try to run the function`TabIcon` however, nothing is called (I placed an alert to confirm nothing was being called). Any thoughts as to why this function isn't running?

```
              <Router>
                <Scene key="root" hideNavBar
                        navigationBarStyle={{backgroundColor: "#fff"}}
                        titleStyle={navTitleStyle}
                        backButtonTintColor={color.black}
                >
                 //Removed other scenes for simplicity
                    <Scene key="Main" tabs={true} initial={this.state.isLoggedIn}>    
                 //This is where i call TabIcon
                        <Scene icon={TabIcon} iconName='timer' key="tab1" component={Home} />                  
                </Scene>
            </Router>
```

Above the components section is my function I try calling:

```
function TabIcon(props) {
    alert('hi');
    return (
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Icon
          name={props.iconName}
          size={26}
          />
      </View>
    </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: How are you defining `alert()` here ? Try `console.log`

Comment: @PritishVaidya haha hi again, unfortunately changing to console log doesn't help. The function simply isn't being called for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I think **icon** is used to set tab icon and it not called any function, for calling any function you need to use **onPress**

```
 <Scene 
    key="myTab" 
    title="My Tab" 
    icon={MyTabIcon} 
    onPress={()=> {
     ...
    }}
   >
```